# Reading/Writing Nibbles (without bit fields) in C/C++

Tags: c++, c, byte, bit-fields

Is there an easy way to read/write a nibble in a byte without using bit fields?
I'll always need to read both nibbles, but will need to write each nibble individually.

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use masks :

```
char byte;
byte = (byte & 0xF0) | (nibble1 & 0xF); // write low quartet
byte = (byte & 0x0F) | ((nibble2 & 0xF) << 4); // write high quartet
```

You may want to put this inside macros.

Comment: If you're updating an existing value, you need to clear the nibble in `byte` before orring in the new value. `byte = (byte & ~0xF) | (nibble1 & 0xF)`, and similarly for the top nibble.

Comment: wouldn't name a variable byte

Comment: There are a couple of mistakes in the above code - you need a `~` in front of the byte masks.

Comment: I'd always go with a function instead of a macro where possible!

Comment: @Alexandre C.: OK - it looks someone else fixed it for you in a different way now

Comment: This works really well, actually, but I found I had to make sure byte=0 before I started because my compiler was filling it with garbage.

Comment: Where are nibble1 and nibble2 defined?

Answer (score 2):

The smallest unit you can work with is a single byte.  If you want to manage the bits you should use [bitwise operators](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4ke0e88k(VS.71).aspx).

Answer (score 1):

Here's a modern answer that takes C++11 into account:

```cpp
// Fixed-width integer types
#include <cstdint>

// Constexpr construction
constexpr uint8_t makeByte(uint8_t highNibble, uint8_t lowNibble)
{
    return (((highNibble & 0xF) << 4) | ((lowNibble & 0xF) << 0));
}

// Constexpr high nibble extraction
constexpr uint8_t getHighNibble(uint8_t byte)
{
    return ((byte >> 4) & 0xF);
}

// Constexpr low nibble extraction
constexpr uint8_t getLowNibble(uint8_t byte)
{
    return ((byte >> 0) & 0xF);
}
```

Big benefits:

- No nasty `union` trickery
- No ugly macros
- No boilerplate
- Using standardised fixed-width types
- `contexpr` functions

  - (I.e. can be used in compile-time calculations and template paramters.)
- Just plain simple

(Before anyone asks, the `>> 0` and `<< 0` are for primarily for visual balance, to demonstrate that the same concept is in use even in the exceptional case where no shift is actually needed. If your compiler doesn't optimise those away, complain to your compiler provider, not me.)

---

However, if your nibbles actually represent something important, e.g. a bitfield, then you *might* want to create a `class`/`struct`.

For example if you were programming a device that required a frame buffer with index 16-colour values, with 2 pixel values packed per byte, you might want to create something like this:

```cpp
struct PixelPair
{
private:
    uint8_t value;

public:
    contexpr explicit PixelPair(uint8_t rawValue) :
        value { rawValue }
    {
    }

    constexpr PixelPair(uint8_t leftPixel, uint8_t rightPixel) :
        value { makeByte(leftPixel, rightPixel) }
    {
    }
    
    constexpr uint8_t getLeftPixel() const
    {
        return getHighNibble(this->value);
    }
    
    constexpr uint8_t getRightPixel() const
    {
        return getLowNibble(this->value);
    }
    
    constexpr uint8_t getRawValue() const
    {
        return this->value;
    }
};
```

Note that this is essentially just a vanishingly thin wrapper around the above functions.

In this case it provides:

- Type safety - No accidentally mixing up a plain old `uint8_t` and a specifically designated `PixelPair`. (See also: [Bjarne Stroustrup's 2012 Keynote](https://youtu.be/OB-bdWKwXsU?t=1146), where he discusses "Type-rich Programming".)
- Improved readability - `pixelPair.getLeftPixel()` tells you exactly what the code is dealing with: the left-hand pixel of a pair of pixels.
- Clear semantics - The code tells you *what* it is dealing with, not *how* it is dealing with it. `pixelPair.getLeftPixel()` tells you that the function is retrieving the left-hand pixel without specifying how, whereas `getHighNibble(pixelByte)` only tells you the *how*, i.e. that the high nibble of a pixel byte is being retrieved, it doesn't tell you *what* that nibble represents - perhaps the high nibble actually represents the right-hand pixel?

You could take this further and create a `Pixel` class too if you wanted even more type safety, and it could have relevant functions for dealing with the specific pixel format. This sort of code gets you thinking about what kind of data you are dealing with and the relationships between the data, rather than just thinking about the data as quantities of bits and bytes.

Answer (score -2):

You could create yourself a pseudo union for convenience:

```
union ByteNibbles
{
    ByteNibbles(BYTE hiNibble, BYTE loNibble)
    {
        data = loNibble;
        data |= hiNibble << 4;
    }

    BYTE data;
};
```

Use it like this:

```
ByteNibbles byteNibbles(0xA, 0xB);

BYTE data = byteNibbles.data;
```

Comment: It's a pseudo union to reinforce a concept.  I'd prefer it to a couple of buggy macros.

Comment: I prefer inline functions to both macros and pseudo unions. ;-)

Comment: If you're going to use this approach, don't make it a `union`, make it a `struct`, and don't construct an object just to immediately discard it, keep the object around. If you find you don't gain any benefit from holding onto a "`ByteNibbles`" then a simple `makeByte(high, low)` function would suffice in the first place.