# How do I combine 4 2-bit values into 1 8-bit value?

Tags: c++, c, bit-manipulation, bit, bit-shift

This code is what I am using to combine 4 2-bit values (unsigned chars but they only hold values from 0-3) into 1 single unsigned char value

```
unsigned char nibble = 0;

nibble = (nibble & 0x03) | (output[i] & 0x03);
nibble = (nibble & 0x0C) | (output[i+1] & 0x03) << 2);
nibble = (nibble & 0x30) | (output[i+2] & 0x03) << 4);
nibble = (nibble & 0xC0) | (output[i+3] & 0x03) << 6);
```

It produces an incorrect value for everything except 00 00 00 00 (it often produces the same result for 2 different sets of 2-bit values).

I'm confused because the code above is an edit of [this code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3110306/reading-writing-nibbles-without-bit-fields-in-c-c), which works fine to combine 2 4-bit values into 1 byte, so why does my version not combine 4 2-bit values into 1 byte?

```
char byte;
byte = (byte & 0xF0) | (nibble1 & 0xF); // write low quartet
byte = (byte & 0x0F) | ((nibble2 & 0xF) << 4); // write high quartet
```

I've tried changing 0x03 / 0x0C / 0x30 / 0xC0 to 0xC0 / 0x30 / 0x0C / 0x03, still wrong. Same for changing & 0x03 to & 0xC0.

Comment: Personnally, I wouldn't bother doing the mask thing and simply add the values directly. The code is larger, but faster if you don't have a compiler that does a lot of optimisation. 

First line : `nibble |= output[i];` Second line: `nibble <<= 2;` However it shouldn't solve your issue. (Oh well it does since the issue is around your = operator.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's because you clear bits in the nibble each time.

That is, when you say this:

```
nibble = (nibble & 0xC0)
```

what you are really saying is "throw away all the work I've done so far, except for the bits at positions 3 and 4".

This code (untested) will probably solve your problem:

```
unsigned char nibble = 0;

nibble |= (output[i  ] & 0x03);
nibble |= (output[i+1] & 0x03) << 2;
nibble |= (output[i+2] & 0x03) << 4;
nibble |= (output[i+3] & 0x03) << 6;
```

If it's *really* true that `output[i+x]` only holds values in the range *[0,3]*, then you can change the code as follows:

```
unsigned char nibble = 0;

assert(0<=output[i  ] && output[i  ]<=3)
nibble |= output[i  ];
assert(0<=output[i+1] && output[i+1]<=3)
nibble |= output[i+1] << 2;
assert(0<=output[i+2] && output[i+2]<=3)
nibble |= output[i+2] << 4;
assert(0<=output[i+3] && output[i+3]<=3)
nibble |= output[i+3] << 6;
```

The asserts could, of course, be removed if you're *really, really* sure. But you can also leave them in and have the compiler extirpate them by using the `NDEBUG` flag (`g++ -DNDEBUG mycode.cpp`). See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5354314/how-to-completely-disable-assertion) for further details.

Comment: If OP's statement `(unsigned chars but they only hold values from 0-3)` is guaranteed, the 4 instances of `& 0x03` can be omitted.

Answer (score 0):

That's because before populating `nibble` with the new bits you are filtering it with a mask that if anything does the opposite of what it should do.

```
nibble = (nibble & 0x03) | (output[i] & 0x03);
nibble = (nibble & 0x0C) | (output[i+1] & 0x03) << 2);
nibble = (nibble & 0x30) | (output[i+2] & 0x03) << 4);
nibble = (nibble & 0xC0) | (output[i+3] & 0x03) << 6);
                   ^^^^ in here you preserve the bits
             you want to replace and zero out everything else
```

Inverting that mask would work:

```
nibble = (nibble & ~0x03) | (output[i] & 0x03);
nibble = (nibble & ~0x0C) | (output[i+1] & 0x03) << 2);
nibble = (nibble & ~0x30) | (output[i+2] & 0x03) << 4);
nibble = (nibble & ~0xC0) | (output[i+3] & 0x03) << 6);
```

However, since `nibble` already starts as `0` anyway, you don't need that. Just populate the bits as in [Richard's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45603221/156811).